# wsgi user permissions on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using elastic beanstalk and django. One of my dependencies in my requirements.txt file has some setup the it performs when it's initially imported. Part of the setup is to check whether a dir exists else it create it. I'm getting permissions errors because the user ( I assume it's wsgi) does not have the permissions to create the dir.

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/wsgi/.newspaper_scraper/memoized'
```

How can I setup permissions to allow for these dirs to be created in a way that will be persistent across instances I create in the future?

Comment: Can you paste your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: I might have worded the question a bit strangely by mentioning requirements. here is the settings file in the 3rd party package i mentioned. https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/master/newspaper/settings.py

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the uWSGI worker is running under a user with limited permissions. You need to create the `.newspaper_scraper/memoized` directory first, and set the correct permissions on it (allow others to r/w). You can do this on deployment by making a script in `.ebextensions` that EB executes upon deployment.

Create a file in `.ebextensions/setup_newspaper.config` and add the following to it:

**.ebextensions/setup_newspaper.config**

```
packages:
  yum:
    libxslt-devel: []
    libxml2-devel: []
    libjpeg-devel: []
    zlib1g-devel: []
    libpng12-devel: []

container_commands:
  01_setup_newspaper:
    command: mkdir -p /home/wsgi/.newspaper_scraper/memoized && chmod 644 /home/wsgi/.newspaper_scraper/memoized
```

*PS: It looks like `newspaper` requires some extra packages to be installed, so I added them too.*

---

Read more info on **.ebextensions** here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html#create-deploy-python-custom-container